# Connection to MongoDB not closing on crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I routinely have > 15 connections open to MongoDB from my Express app.

Every time my Express app crashes and reboots, it seems like the connection to MongoDB stays alive and Mongoose creates a new one.

How do I fix this?

Comment: what condition did you check if it is still alive about crash, i find that very strange.

Comment: I didn't check it, it just seems like it, as the number increases every time my server crashes @CaspainCaldion

Comment: @softcode How are you checking this number?